# Проблема с массивами в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, delete

Есть простой скрипт на python, который считывает юзеров с файла (1 строка - 1 юзер) и обрабатывает их. В итоге мне нужно получить список юзеров, которых осталось обработать. В примере ниже код упрощён, в оригинальном коде при обработке можно указать количество юзеров, которое нужно обработать, то есть программа проходит базу не до конца, а затем выгружает юзеров, которых осталось обработать. По моей задумке каждый обработанный юзер удаляется из массива, которому перед обработкой присваивается значение массива с полученными юзерами. Вот сам код:

```
len_base = 0
added_users = 0

cur_users_list = []
result_user_list = []
path = 'base_users.txt'

try:
    f = open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    users = f.read()
    cur_users_list = users.split('\n')
    len_base = len(cur_users_list)

    print()
    print(f'Найдено пользователей: {len_base}.')

except Exception as e:
    print(f'Ошибка чтения файла: {e}.')

cur_position = 1
result_user_list = cur_users_list

for user in cur_users_list:

    added_users += 1
    print()
    print(f'Пользователь {user} успешно обработан.')
    print(f'Обработанные пользователи: {added_users}/{len_base}.')

    cur_user = user
    if cur_user in result_user_list:
        result_user_list.remove(cur_user)

    cur_position += 1

print()
print(f'Обработано пользователей: {added_users}')
```

Но этот код проходит только половину юзеров, то есть он обрабатывает только каждого второго. Тут дело в этих строчках с удалением из массива:

```
cur_user = user
    if cur_user in result_user_list:
        result_user_list.remove(cur_user)
```

Почему-то `user` удаляется и из массива `cur_users_list`, хотя я его удаляю из ранее созданного массива `result_user_list`, я даже сделала переменную `cur_user`, чтобы не использовать `user`, но результат остался прежним, я не могу понять в чём проблема. У меня ещё есть идея добавлять обработанных юзеров в массив `result_user_list`, а потом сравнивать его с `cur_users_list` и оставить только необработанных юзеров, но я хочу разобраться почему такой результат выдаёт текущий код. Вот файл `base_users.txt`:

```
Тит
Виктор
Альберт
Игорь
Цицерон
Сергей
Елисей
Жигер
Давид
Люций
Донат
Максим
Эрик
Любомир
Ленар
Жерар
Юрий
Феликс
Михаил
Чеслав
Юрий
Лаврентий
Чарльз
Харитон
Юлий
Тарас
Шерлок
Фёдор
Евгений
Яромир
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас типичная ошибка, которая тут много раз обсуждалась в вопросах. Вы копируете не сам список, а **ссылку** на него. Поэтому все изменения, которые вы делаете в одном списке тут же отображаются на другом списке - потому что это один список, на который у вас есть две ссылки.

```
result_user_list = cur_users_list
```

Чтобы скопировать именно содержимое списка, а не просто ссылку, можно сделать так:

```
result_user_list = cur_users_list.copy()
```

Comment: спасибо большое! это помогло.